# unable to find a destination in xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

After executing this command getting error

```
xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=<udid>' test
```

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:<udid> }

    The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

    Available destinations for the "WebDriverAgentRunner" scheme:
        { platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, variant:Mac Catalyst, id:00B9EE23-6C05-53C6-8661-775B8F1E5F68 }
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
        { platform:macOS, variant:Mac Catalyst, name:Any Mac }
        { platform:iOS, id:b8f8c7bb18de6b9fa6793f33c4f5604e7cf0763e, name:Vandana’s iPhone }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FA976777-3880-453C-9659-B4E0856BF6FB, OS:16.2, name:iPad (10th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4F04B104-BDCF-475A-BEE8-346D4B5958D9, OS:16.2, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7645AE63-1328-4134-868C-97F2DA4E2089, OS:16.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7AAC0380-D6B2-4A7E-9F2A-78203131BD96, OS:16.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2F27669B-0E15-4475-B6BA-2EC78C01905E, OS:16.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0E74D044-4FC1-4A35-B9F2-D6121E3928F7, OS:16.2, name:iPhone 14 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2B2547A2-C806-457B-A81D-42F5D0FFB86E, OS:16.2, name:iPhone 14 Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D58E417C-E580-495F-A3BA-9F4508AD57D4, OS:16.2, name:iPhone 14 Pro }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8AB9C689-C7A7-444F-AD39-06604B34D922, OS:16.2, name:iPhone 14 Pro Max }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:14AE8049-E49A-417A-A8AA-3F03C9373130, OS:16.2, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
```

want to connect device to system but getting this error.

```
usibg MACos:monterey
      xcode:14.2
      ios:15.7.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcodebuild: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751542/xcodebuild-unable-to-find-a-destination-matching-the-provided-destination-speci)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!